# Directives with static value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

If I use an AngularJS directive with a static value, let's say:

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="true" />
```

My question around this:

Will this directive be re-evaluated on AngularJS cycles leading to a drop on performance? (think on a heavier scenario)

Comment: A solution may be to bind once on the parent directive. 2014 NG-Conf as a youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y)  on this and how to not take such a performance hit. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Will this directive be re-evaluated on AngularJS cycles`:

Yes, the value of `ng-readonly` is an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and this expression *could* be a more complex ternary or function reference.  So, the directive *must* do dirty checking on it (for the more complex cases).

`leading to a drop on performance`

This depends on many things and should be tested and benchmarked before making assumptions.  A *lot* of dirty-checking can happen without any noticeable performance drop.

Since Angular 1.3, you can use the [bind-once](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) syntax (`::`) to possibly not add the value to the watch queue, but I'm not sure about how this would work with `true`:

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="::true" />
```